# Как программно задать margin в dp

Tags: android, android-layout

Изменяю прямо в коде размер RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout fragmentContainer = (RelativeLayout)
                mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(0,56,0,0);
            fragmentContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Как написано в документации,

> Sets the margins, in pixels.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы отступ сверху был равен 56 (или `android:actionBarSize`) в dp

Comment: [посмотри здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914308/7702010) P.S. не отправил комментарием так как не хватило балов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float dp = mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int margin = 56;
            int totalMargin =(int)  dp * margin;
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,totalMargin,0,0);
            fragmentContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**P.S. Спасибо @Dmitry**

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять из ресурсов, тогда система сама переведет в пикселы:

```
int totalMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.total_margin);
layoutParams.setMargins(0,totalMargin,0,0);
fragmentContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

в файле ресурсов dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <dimen name="total_margin">56dp</dimen>
</resources>
```